# what's the elegant way to write this code in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I use Clojure and korma libs.

```
defn db-search-users
  [& {:keys [nick_name max_age min_age page page_size lmt oft]
      :or {lmt 10  page_size 10 oft 0 }
      :as conditons}]
  (let [users-sql  (-> (select* users)
                       (fields :user_name :id :nick_name)
                       (limit (if (nil? page) lmt page_size))
                       (offset (if (nil? page) oft (* page page_size))))]
    (do
       (exec (-> users-sql
                need_do_something_here
             )
       )

  )
```

now I need to add some search conditions to users-sql at "`need_do_something_here`", I can describe it in imperative style:

```
if ( nick_name != nil)
    users-sql = (where users-sql (like :nick_name nick_name)

if (max_age != nil)
    users-sql = (where users-sql (> :birthday blabla....))

if (min_age != nil)
    users-sql = (where users-sql (< :birthday blabla....))
```

how to do this in an elegant way in a functional style?

another question is:

I find the following code ugly:

```
(if (nil? page) lmt page)
```

Is there some functions in Clojure like `(get_default_value_3_if_a_is_null a 3)` ?

Comment: Try *clojure/core.match* at https://github.com/clojure/core.match/wiki/Basic-usage.

Comment: I had read some examples of core.match.It seems only one branch will be executed.But in my case many branches will be executed.

Comment: Take a look at the conditional threading macro, `cond->`. It does not short circuit. For your other question, look at `fnil`. Also since `nil` is falsey you can use `if`, `if-not`, etc. directly (assuming `false` isn't a valid "page").

Comment: `let` in clojure can define multiple local variables, and later variables in a `let` binding sequence can refer to variables defined earlier in the sequence.  It looks like that would allow you to use your multiple `if` strategy pretty much unchanged, but consider A. Webb's suggestion, too.  `(get_default_value_3_if_a_is_null a 3)`: This feels like Clojure maps might be useful to you (i.e. the data structures, not the function).

Comment: You "answered" that you got the answer from the comments. Stack Overflow does not accept "answers" like that. That would be considered a "comment" instead. You can always leave comments on your own questions. Better would be to write up a complete, detailed answer as an "answer" that stands on its own (specify the solution you found in detail), which you can accept later to indicate the question is resolved. I personally appreciate such effort when I leave hints as comments and am inclined to upvote people who answer their own questions with complete, detailed descriptions of the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

get my answer from A.Webb,now my code is :

```
(defn db-search-users
  [& {:keys [nick_name max_age min_age page page_size lmt oft]
      :or   {lmt 10 page_size 10 oft 0}
      :as   conditons}]
  (let [users-sql (-> (select* users)
                      (fields :user_name :id :nick_name :password)
                      (limit (if (nil? page) lmt page_size))
                      (offset (if (nil? page) oft (* page page_size))))
        normal_conditions (select-keys conditons [:user_name :gender :phone])]
    (exec (cond-> users-sql
                  (not-empty normal_conditions) (where normal_conditions)
                  (not-nil? nick_name) (where (like :nick_name (str "%" nick_name "%")))
                  (not-nil? max_age) (where (> :birthday (c/to-sql-date (-> max_age t/years t/ago))))
                  (not-nil? min_age) (where (< :birthday (c/to-sql-date (-> min_age t/years t/ago))))
                  )
          )

    )
  )
```

cond-> is perfect way to deal with my question.

the second question :how to beautify code like

```
(if (nil? page_size) lmt page_size)
```

now get think map data structure can be used for this case.

Comment: To answer to your second question, you can replace `(if (nil? page_size) lmt page_size) ` with `(or page_size lmt)`, assuming again that `false`, the only falsey value but `nil`, isn't a valid `page_size`. But I can't see any such examples in your code. But - on similar grounds - you *can* remove the `not-nil?` tests, so that `(not-nil? nick_name) (...)` becomes `nick_name (...)`.